# On the number of solutions of the equation involving Pochhammer symbols $(n)_a\cdot(n)_b=(n)_c$, for integers greater than or equal to $2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, divisors-multiples

As paticular case of the equation involving Pochhammer symbols $$(n)_a\cdot(m)_b=(k)_c,$$
where the variables are positive integers, I've consider the case $n=m=k$ of previous equation, that is

$$(n)_a\cdot(n)_b=(n)_c\tag{1}$$

for integers $n\geq 2$, $a\geq 2$, $b\geq 2$ and $c\geq 2$, from the definition of Pochhammer symbols, see the section References, I got

$$\frac{(a+n-1)!}{(n-1)!}\cdot \frac{(b+n-1)!}{(n-1)!}=\frac{(c+n-1)!}{(n-1)!}$$

and from this, the equaiton involving factorials 
$$(a+n-1)!\cdot(b+n-1)!=(n-1)!\cdot(c+n-1)!.\tag{1'}$$

I know that in the literature there are problems related to equations involving factorials, thus my question seems a curiosity, but I don't know how to get an idea if the equation has only finitely many solutions over integers greater than or equal to $2$.

> **Question.** I have no idea/intuition if previous equation has only finitely many solutions, is it possible a calculation or reasoning showing that $$(a+n-1)!\cdot(b+n-1)!=(n-1)!\cdot(c+n-1)!$$ does have only finitely many solutions when the variables $n,a,b$ and $c$ run over integers greater than or equal to $2$? **Many thanks.**

I can to find solutions $(n,a,b,c)$ for the segments $2\leq n\leq 70$, $2\leq a\leq 70$, $2\leq b\leq 70$ and $2\leq c\leq 70$ using the outputs of a similar 
 Pari/GP script that I run in the site *Sage Cell Server*

`for(n=2, 20, for(a=2,20, for(b=2, 20, for(c=2, 20, if(((a+n-1)!)*(b+n-1)!==(c+n-1)!*(n-1)!,print(n," ",a," ",b," "c))))))`

just copy and paste previous line to evaluate it, choosing as language *GP*.

The solutions that I know are for (will be multiple solutions) $n=2$ or $n=3,4,5$. As observation from the table below of solutions it seems that typically $c+1=a+b$.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
n& a& b& c\\
2& 2& 4& 5\\
2& 4& 2& 5\\
2& 5& 6& 9\\
2& 6& 5& 9\\
3& 2& 9& 10\\
3& 9& 2& 10\\
4& 2& 16& 17\\
4& 16& 2& 17\\
5& 3& 9& 11\\
5& 9& 3& 11
    \end{matrix}
$$

And I know that Stirling approximation should be an important tool to elucidate how many solutions does have an equation that involves factorials, I mean if our equation has only finitely many soluytions or it is possible that the equation has infinitely many solutions.

### References:

I add as reference for Pochhammer symbols the article from the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld *Pochhammer Symbol* that is a very good reference in Internet.

Comment: The encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld has the article *Pochhammer Symbol* dedicated to this arithmetic sequence, I add it just for reference for all users.

Comment: What's your definition of the Pochhammer symbol?

Comment: Many thanks for your attenton @WlodAA it is definition from the mentioned MathWorld's article *Pochhammer Symbol*, from which the equation $$(a+n-1)!\cdot(b+n-1)!=(n-1)!\cdot(c+n-1)!$$ follows from $(n)_a\cdot(n)_b=(n)_c$.

Comment: Maybe Legendre's formula, I refer the Wikipedia *Legendre's formula*,  for the well-known formulas related to $p$-adic valuation of a positive integer $n$ can be useful here. I don't know, it is just an idea.